# How to force evaluation of symbolic conjugate

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to get variable `test` to equal to variable `test2`.

The print out I get from `test2` is simply `(1-g1 g1*)` as desired.

But `test` spits out `(g1-1)(g1*-1)(x)(x*)`, where `x` is `sqrt{(1- g1 g1*)/[(g1-1)(g1*-1)]}`

Visually looking at the problem, I know that the expression should cancel out, but I cannot get `test` to simplify the conjugate expressions out.

- Sympy version 1.4
- Python 3.7

Have tried sp.simplify, sp.together

```
import sympy as sp

def Lambdaj(gammaj):
    step1 = sp.together(1 - sp.conjugate(gammaj)) * sp.sqrt((1 - gammaj * sp.conjugate(gammaj)) / ((1-gammaj) * (1 - sp.conjugate(gammaj))))
    return step1

g1 = sp.symbols('g1')

test = sp.together(Lambdaj(g1) * sp.conjugate(Lambdaj(g1)))
print(test)

test2 = 1 - g1 * sp.conjugate(g1)
print(test2)

print(sp.together((1-g1)*(1-sp.conjugate(g1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it fair to assume that `g1**2 < 1`? If so, we can replace `g1` with an expression that only takes on these values, simplify the result, and resubstitute the original `g1`:

```
>>> p = var('p',nonnegative=True)
>>> u=Eq(g1, p/(1+p)) # p in [0, 1)
>>> test.subs(*u.args).simplify().subs(p,solve(u,p)[0]).simplify()
1 - g1**2
```

Comment: Neat! You are right-- there is a bound I can add but g1 is a complex number so it is assumed that abs(g1)<1 -- can I constrain g1 as a complex number without breaking it up into real and imaginary components?